# Is there a difference between these two types of methods of proving something for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Let's say we would like to prove that  $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge0$
$$
S(n):\space\prod^n_{k=0}(1+z^{2^{k}})=\frac{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z},\quad z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}
$$
is true.
Now obviously we could just use Mathematical Induction
$$
S(0)= 1+z=\frac{(1+z)(1-z)}{(1-z)}=\frac{1-z^2}{1-z} \quad\checkmark
$$
Assume true for $k$. And now we proof for $k+1$
$$
\begin{align}
\prod^{n+1}_{k=0}(1+z^{2^{k}})&=\prod^{n}_{k=0}(1+z^{2^{k}})(1+z^{2^{n+1}})\\
&=\frac{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z}(1+z^{2^{n+1}})\\
&=\frac{(1-z^{2^{n+1}})(1+z^{2^{n+1}})}{1-z}\\
&=\frac{1-z^{2^{2n+2}}}{1-z}\quad\checkmark
\end{align}
$$
This would obviously be the 'normal' induction way to prove this. Now my question is if this is equivalent to another method that I read in a book because I would prefer to use this other method in an exam but I'm not fully confident if this would get accepted. In this other method we claim that
$$
\space\prod^n_{k=0}(1+z^{2^{k}})=\frac{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z},\quad z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}
$$
is true and show that it is true for $n=0$. The difference with this method is that we claim that our assumption is true for a any but "fixed" $n$. Than we show that
$$
\begin{align}
\prod^{n+1}_{k=0}(1+z^{2^{k}})&=\prod^{n}_{k=0}(1+z^{2^{k}})(1+z^{2^{n+1}})\\
\frac{1-z^{2^{n+2}}}{1-z}&=\frac{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z}(1+z^{2^{n+1}})\\
1-z^{2^{n+2}}&=(1-z^{2^{n+1}})(1+z^{2^{n+1}})\\
1-z^{2^{n+2}}&=1+z^{2^{n+1}}-z^{2^{n+1}}-z^{2^{n+2}}\\
1-z^{2^{n+2}}&=1-z^{2^{n+2}} \quad \checkmark
\end{align}
$$
We have shown, that both sides are equal and therefore follows
$$
\Rightarrow \begin{align}
\prod^{n+1}_{k=0}(1+z^{2^{k}})&=\frac{1-z^{2^{2n+2}}}{1-z}.
\end{align}
$$
My question would be if both methods are equivalent because I am still unsure whether my professor is going to accept this on the exam if I use this instead of doing the 'normal' induction method. Can you please help or elaborate on your opinion?

Comment: The only person who can answer the question "would my professor accept this on an exam" is your professor.  You should ask her!

Comment: @JBL I know but can you at least tell me whether you think that this is mathematically correct and have you seen this method before?

Comment: There are not two methods here, there are two different ways of writing a proof by induction.  The first way of writing the proof is much clearer, it is easy to tell what is going on, and in particular it is easy to tell what the author is thinking.  The second method is less transparent.  (It also contains some confusion around the question of the base case.)  ...

Comment: When I am something intended for an audience of professional mathematicians (say, when I am refereeing a journal article) I do not have any problem with induction proofs that are abbreviated in this way.  However, when I am grading work written by students who are just learning to write proofs, it is much more important to me that they write out full details of everything -- they have not yet earned the presumption that they know how to fill in the details.  You should talk to your professor about the difference between the two methods, and what she expects from you.

Comment: @JBL Makes sense. Thank you!